# nested angularjs controller: how one controller can communicate with another controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my html view:

```
<div id="chatContainer">
    <div id="users" ng-controller="usersController">
        <div ng-repeat="user in users" class="userItem">{{user.username}}</div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatText" ng-controller="chatTextController">
        <div ng-repeat="text in texts" class="text">{{text.text}}</div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatInput" ng-controller="chatInputController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter chat text here" id="chatInputTxt" ng-model="chatInputTxt">
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to write the chatInputController controller so when user types in chatInputTxt, texts in chatTextController are updated, saying differently:

How can chatInputController access/communicate with chatTextController  ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$emit` or `$broadcast` whenever possible, as the more services that require these the more of a troubleshooting mess you can get into.

Nested controllers in Angular.js automatically receive a copy of their parents' scope. To answer your question, *it's all automatic.*

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
  {{mySharedValue}} // bar
  <div ng-controller="controller2">
    {{mySharedValue }} // also bar
  </div>
</div>
```

JS...

```
function controller1($scope) { $scope.mySharedValue = foo; $scope.notify = function() {
   console.log("I'm notified!") 
}; }
function controller2($scope) { $scope.mySharedValue = bar; $scope.notify(); // logs "i'm notified!" }
```

Comment: When controller 2 sets the value of `mySharedValue` it will create a new instance of `mySharedValue` on that controller, FYI

Comment: I'm not sure how that works... can you share reference from docs?

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options:

1. You can use `$broadcast` and `$on` to communicate with sibling controllers
2. You have a parent controller, you can set objects on that controller to be shared with the child controllers (just be sure you understand Angular $scope inheritance or things are going to get confusing, quickly). - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
3. Use a shared service to access from each controller

Comment: can you explain more about 2) ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use $emit or $broadcast to generate an event and pass some data.

- $broadcast - send the event downwards to all child scopes.
- $emit - send the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.

  $scope.$broadcast('eventName', param1, param2);

  So you could broadcast from $rootScope.  Then in the other controller use

  $scope.$on('eventName', function(param1, param2) {
  })

  to catch the event.

You could also use a service and setup a watch on the service in each of your controllers.  Or you could have a parent controller instead of polluting the rootScope and do a broadcast from the parent controller.

If the communication is only one way, from the child scope to the parent scope then emit would work from the child controller.